# PHP: is_dir() within loop condition doesn't work

Tags: php, file-io

I just want to index all files in the current directory:

```php
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== FALSE) {
        if (is_dir($file)) continue;
        echo "<p><strong>$file</strong>: is_dir($file)? "
             .(is_dir($file)?"&#10004;":"&#10006;")."</p>\n";
    }            
    closedir($handle);
}
```

.. outputs:

---

index.php: is_dir(index.php)? ✖

readdir.php: is_dir(readdir.php)? ✖

---

But placing the is_dir(..) inside the loop condition

```php
while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== FALSE && !is_dir($file)) {
    ...
}
```

.. returns **nothing**!

I know is_dir(..) returns always a boolean value. So what's wrong with my expression?
Just for completeness: PHP 5.4.14 on a IIS 7.5 by FastCGI on a Windows 7 SP1.

Thanks

Comment: And yes, I might use [glob("\*.\*")](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I realized what **array_filter([array], [callback])** is doing I came to a better solution meeting the "all files in the *current* directory" requirement more closely:

```php
foreach  (array_filter(scandir('.'), "is_file") as $file) {
    echo "<p><strong>$file</strong>: is_dir($file)? "
         .(is_dir($file)?"&#10004;":"&#10006;")."</p>\n";
}
```

Nevertheless: Thanks to @Alma!!!

Answer (score 3):

That is so because your first dir in list will be `".."`, then `is_dir()` returns true and your cycle ends. Remember - `while` loop will be continued until condition is true and, if it is not, cycle will end.

To get the thing working - do this:

```
$rgFiles = array_filter(glob('/path/to/files'), 'is_file');
```

Comment: Yeah. You're right. Sorry for my stupid question! I'am not familar with the PHP typical file iteration by using a complete statement.